# Upperbound on harmonic number discrete math

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How do I show $H_{2^k} \leq k + 1$ for each $k \geq 0$?

I don't know how to do this question so can anyone help me?

Comment: If you can say a little bit about what you know/have tried (even if it's not very much), you're likely to get a better response. Try at least giving us the definition of a harmonic number.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your questions. This renders them useless to others and is disrespectful to the efforts of those who have provided answers.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** You can prove it by induction. To get from $H_{2^k}$ to $H_{2^{k+1}}$, you add $2^k$ terms, each of which is $\lt \frac{1}{2^k}$.